# word files get corrupt when transferred to client side using sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

this code transfers all files except office file like docx and pdf. need a fix. Files with large sizes are being transferred and are not corrupted but the problem persists with only word or pdf or powerpoint or excel files.

this is client side code

```
FileInputStream reader= new FileInputStream(new File(path));
byte[] buffer=new byte[512];
int count=0;
dataSendingStream.writeUTF("upload");

System.out.println(filename);
dataSendingStream.writeUTF(filename);

dataSendingStream.writeInt(count);
System.out.println(count);
do
{
    count=reader.read(buffer);
    dataSendingStream.writeInt(count);
    if(count!=-1)
        dataSendingStream.write(buffer);
    if(count!=-1)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<512;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("item "+i+" in buffer is     "+Byte.toString(buffer[i]));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(buffer);
    System.out.println(count);
}
while(count!=-1);
```

this is the server side code

```
String filename=fins.readUTF();
File file=new File("E:\\repository\\"+filename);
BufferedOutputStream writer=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
int count=fins.readInt();
byte[] buffer=new byte[512];
while(count!=-1)
{
    System.out.println(count);
    count=fins.readInt();
    if(count==-1)
        break;
    fins.read(buffer);
    for(int i=0;i<512;i++)
        System.out.println("item "+i+" in buffer is "+Byte.toString(buffer[i]));
    writer.write(buffer);
}

writer.flush();
System.out.println("file written");
writer.close();
System.out.println("file recieved");
```

Comment: not related to your problem but why you have this `while(count!=-1);`

Comment: @SpringLearner It's the end of a do/while statement.

Comment: @EJP My bad, I did not see there is a do statement